# A question on definite integration

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \quad if \quad 1/2^n<x\leq 1/2^{n-1}$$ $x$ belongs to $[0,1]$, n belongs to natural numbers and $f(0)=0$. Find the value of the integral of $f(x)$ from 0 to 1.

If I put $n=1$ I get the interval $1/2<x\leq 1$ and for other values of $n$ I get smaller and smaller intervals. Event though I am able to get a slight picture here I am having difficulty in proceeding further. I would like some hints on how to approach this problem.

Comment: After you evaluate the first few integrals by breaking the original integral into intervals, you would see a pattern while summing them upto $\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hint: 
$$
\int_{0}^{1} f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{\frac{1}{2^n}}^{\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}} f
$$

Comment: Ohh... Thank you. So I just integrate the function and find the converging limit of the series right?

Comment: Should work. In each of those subintervals, you know which value the function has, so it's easily integrated.